# Implementation of Bakery Algorithm in C for forked processes

Tags: c, algorithm, fork, exec, shared-memory

So, I'm new to shared memory and the shm functions in C.

I've got two programs; master and slave. In the most general sense: the master program creates a `sharedNum` integer in shared memory and forks off multiple processes that exec the slave program. The slave program processes must then increment `sharedNum` from shared memory (perhaps multiple times, even) and print it to a specified file. I am 100% confident that everything is working (though it may look messy) aside from the shared memory manipulation. I've been testing throughout development.

The problem I'm having is with race conditions in the slave program processes. I understand that I need to implement the Bakery algorithm in order to lock and unlock processes from accessing the critical section. The lack of this causes `sharedNum` manipulation to be off.

I attempted to implement a form of the Bakery algorithm in my slave program, but it doesn't seem to work... Through testing, I've discovered that the `choosing` and `turnNum` variables (which I NEED to use for the Bakery algorithm, as far as I understand) are themselves experiencing race conditions. How is this avoidable? I'm pretty sure they need to be in shared memory as well, otherwise they couldn't be updated by multiple processes...

Thanks in advance.

Program dumps follow.

master.c:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<sys/ipc.h>
#include<sys/shm.h>

// global variables
pid_t *children;
int slave_max;

// globals relating to shared memory
key_t shmkey;
int shmid_sharedNum;
int *sharedNum;

void handle_sigalrm(int signum, siginfo_t *info, void *ptr)
{
   // prevents multiple interrupts
   signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);

   fprintf(stderr, "Master ran out of time\n");

   // detaching and deleting shared memory
   shmdt(sharedNum);
   shmctl(shmid_sharedNum, IPC_RMID, NULL);

   // creating tmp_children to replace children
   // this way children can be freed before SIGTERM
   pid_t tmp_children[slave_max];
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < slave_max; i++);
   {
      tmp_children[i] = children[i];
   }

   // freeing allocated memory
   free(children);

   // terminate child processes
   for (i = 0; i < slave_max; i++)
   {
      kill(tmp_children[i], SIGTERM);
   }
}

void handle_sigint(int signum, siginfo_t *info, void *ptr)
{
   // prevents multiple interrupts
   signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);
   signal(SIGALRM, SIG_IGN);

   fprintf(stderr, " interrupt was caught by master\n");

   // detaching and deleting shared memory
   shmdt(sharedNum);
   shmctl(shmid_sharedNum, IPC_RMID, NULL);

   // creating tmp_children to replace children
   // this way children can be freed before SIGTERM
   pid_t tmp_children[slave_max];
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < slave_max; i++)
   {
      tmp_children[i] = children[i];
   }

   // freeing allocated memory
   free(children);

   // terminate child processes
   for (i = 0; i < slave_max; i++)
   {
      kill(tmp_children[i], SIGTERM);
   }
}

void catch_sigalrm()
{
   static struct sigaction _sigact;
   memset(&_sigact, 0, sizeof(_sigact));
   _sigact.sa_sigaction = handle_sigalrm;
   _sigact.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
   sigaction(SIGALRM, &_sigact, NULL);
}

void catch_sigint()
{
   static struct sigaction _sigact;
   memset(&_sigact, 0, sizeof(_sigact));
   _sigact.sa_sigaction = handle_sigint;
   _sigact.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
   sigaction(SIGINT, &_sigact, NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   // default variables
   int i = 0; // to be used as a counter variable
   slave_max = 5;
   char slave_max_str[25]; // arbitrary size
   char *log_filename = NULL;
   int slave_increment = 3;
   char slave_increment_str[25]; // arbitrary size
   int master_time = 20;

   // shared memory initialization
   shmkey = ftok("./master", 118371); // arbitrary key
   shmid_sharedNum = shmget(shmkey, sizeof(sharedNum), 0600 | IPC_CREAT);
   sharedNum = (int *)shmat(shmid_sharedNum, NULL, 0);
   sharedNum[0] = 0;

   // handling command line args with getopt
   int c;
   while((c = getopt(argc, argv, "hs:l:i:t:")) != -1)
   {
      switch(c)
      {
         // -h : program help
         case 'h':
            // the following if-else block makes sure
            // that -h will be used by itself
            if (argc == 2)
            {
               printf("%s -h : program help\n", argv[0]);
               printf("%s -s [integer] : set max number of slave processes\n", argv[0]);
               printf("%s -l [filename] : set log filename\n", argv[0]);
               printf("%s -i [integer] : set slave process incrementer\n", argv[0]);
               printf("%s -t [integer] : set number of seconds master will terminate\n", argv[0]);
               exit(0);
            }
            else
            {
               fprintf(stderr, "%s: option must be used by itself -- 'h'\n", argv[0]);
               exit(1);
            }
         // -s [integer] : set max number of slave processes
         case 's':
            slave_max = atoi(optarg);
            break;
         // -l [filename] : set log filename
         case 'l':
            log_filename = optarg;
            break;
         // -i [integer] : set slave process incrementer
         case 'i':
            slave_increment = atoi(optarg);
            break;
         // -t [integer] : set number of seconds master will terminate
         case 't':
            master_time = atoi(optarg);
            break;
         // the following case takes care of user input errors
         case '?':
            if (optopt == 's')
               fprintf(stderr, "Error: -s requires an integer\n");
            else if (optopt == 'l')
               fprintf(stderr, "Error: -l requires a filename\n");
            else if (optopt == 'i')
               fprintf(stderr, "Error: -i requires an integer\n");
            else if (optopt == 't')
               fprintf(stderr, "Error: -t requires an integer\n");
            else if (isprint(optopt))
               fprintf(stderr, "Error: input can't be printed\n");
            else
               fprintf(stderr, "Error: invalid syntax\n");
            exit(1);
         default:
            abort();
      }
   }

   catch_sigint();
   catch_sigalrm();
   alarm(master_time);

   // if log_filename wasn't passed in by -l,
   // its default value is set here...
   if (!log_filename)
      log_filename = "test.out";

   // setting slave_increment_str and slave_max_str
   // for use in future execl
   snprintf(slave_increment_str, 25, "%i", slave_increment);
   snprintf(slave_max_str, 25, "%i", slave_max);

   // initializing pids
   if ((children = (pid_t *)(malloc(slave_max * sizeof(pid_t)))) == NULL)
   {
      errno = ENOMEM;
      perror("children malloc");
      exit(1);
   }
   pid_t p;

   // forking off child processes
   for (i = 0; i < slave_max; i++)
   {
      p = fork();
      if (p < 0)
      {
         fprintf(stderr,"Error: fork failed\n");
         continue;
      }
      if (p == 0)
      {
         children[i] = p;
         execl("./slave", "slave", "-l", log_filename, "-s", slave_max_str, "-i", slave_increment_str, (char *) NULL);
         exit(0);
      }
   }

   // waiting for all child processes to finish
   for (i = 0; i < slave_max; i++)
   {
      int status;
      waitpid(children[i], &status, 0);
   }

   // clean up and finish
   free(children);
   shmdt(sharedNum);
   shmctl(shmid_sharedNum, IPC_RMID, NULL);
   return 0;
}
```

slave.c:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<sys/ipc.h>
#include<sys/shm.h>

// global variables
pid_t parent;
pid_t child;
int childProc;

// globals for shared memory
key_t shmkey;
int shmid_sharedNum, shmid_choosing, shmid_turnNum;
int *sharedNum; int *choosing; int *turnNum;

void handle_sigterm(int signum, siginfo_t *info, void *ptr)
{
   // detaching and deleting shared memory
   shmdt(sharedNum);
   shmdt(choosing);
   shmdt(turnNum);
   shmctl(shmid_sharedNum, IPC_RMID, NULL);
   shmctl(shmid_choosing, IPC_RMID, NULL);
   shmctl(shmid_turnNum, IPC_RMID, NULL);

   fprintf(stderr, "Process #%i was terminated by master\n", childProc);
   exit(0);
}

void catch_sigterm()
{
   static struct sigaction _sigact;
   memset(&_sigact, 0, sizeof(_sigact));
   _sigact.sa_sigaction = handle_sigterm;
   _sigact.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
   sigaction(SIGTERM, &_sigact, NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   // default variables
   parent = getppid();
   child = getpid();
   childProc = (int)(child - parent);
   int i, j, maxCounter; // to be used as a counter variables
   int slave_max = 1;
   char *log_filename = NULL;
   int slave_incrementer = 3;
   srand(time(NULL));
   int napTime;

   // shared memory initialization
   shmkey = ftok("./master", 118371); // arbitrary key
   shmid_sharedNum = shmget(shmkey, sizeof(sharedNum), 0600 | IPC_CREAT);
   sharedNum = (int *)shmat(shmid_sharedNum, NULL, 0);
   shmid_choosing = shmget(shmkey, sizeof(choosing), 0600 | IPC_CREAT);
   choosing = (int *)shmat(shmid_choosing, NULL, 0);
   shmid_turnNum = shmget(shmkey, sizeof(turnNum), 0600 | IPC_CREAT);
   turnNum = (int *)shmat(shmid_turnNum, NULL, 0);

   catch_sigterm();
   signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);

   // implementing getopt to handle command line args
   int c;
   while((c = getopt(argc, argv, "s:l:i:")) != -1)
   {
      switch(c)
      {
         // -s [integer] : number of slave processes
         case 's':
            slave_max = atoi(optarg);
         // -l [filename] : set log filename
         case 'l':
            log_filename = optarg;
            break;
         // -i [integer] : set slave process incrementer
         case 'i':
        slave_incrementer = atoi(optarg);
            break;
         // this case takes care of user input errors
         case '?':
            if (optopt == 's')
               fprintf(stderr, "Error: -s requires an integer\n");
            else if (optopt == 'l')
               fprintf(stderr, "Error: -l requires a filename\n");
            else if (optopt == 'i')
               fprintf(stderr, "Error: -i requires an integer\n");
            else if (isprint(optopt))
               fprintf(stderr, "Error: input can't be printed\n");
            else
               fprintf(stderr, "Error: invalid syntax\n");
            exit(1);
         default:
            abort();
      }
   }

   // if log_filename wasn't passed in by -l,
   // its default value is set here...
   if (!log_filename)
      log_filename = "test.out";

   struct timespec now;
   long curTime;
   int max = 0;
   for (i = 0; i < slave_incrementer; i++)
   {
      // execute code to enter critical section
      choosing[(childProc-1)] = 1;
      for (maxCounter = 0; maxCounter < slave_max; maxCounter++)
      {
          if((turnNum[maxCounter]) > max)
             max = (turnNum[maxCounter]);
      }
      turnNum[(childProc-1)] = 1 + max;
      printf("turnNum for process #%i = %i\n", childProc, turnNum[(childProc-1)]);
      choosing[(childProc-1)] = 0;
      for (j = 0; j < slave_max; j++)
      {
     while (choosing[j] == 1) {}
         while ((turnNum[j] != 0) && (turnNum[j] < turnNum[(childProc-1)])) {}
      }

      // critical section
      napTime = rand() % 3;
      sleep(napTime);
      sharedNum[0]++;
      clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &now);
      curTime = ((((long)now.tv_sec) * 1000000000) + (long)now.tv_nsec);
      // write message to log file here
         // for testing purposes:
         printf("File modified by process #%i (increment %i) at time %ld with sharedNum = %i\n", childProc, (i+1), curTime, sharedNum[0]);
      napTime = rand() % 3;
      sleep(napTime);

      // exit from critical section
      turnNum[(childProc-1)] = 0;
   }

   // clean up and finish
   shmdt(sharedNum);
   shmdt(choosing);
   shmdt(turnNum);
   shmctl(shmid_sharedNum, IPC_RMID, NULL);
   shmctl(shmid_choosing, IPC_RMID, NULL);
   shmctl(shmid_turnNum, IPC_RMID, NULL);
   return 0;
}
```

(Broken) Bakery algorithm section of slave.c:

```
  // execute code to enter critical section
  choosing[(childProc-1)] = 1;
  for (maxCounter = 0; maxCounter < slave_max; maxCounter++)
  {
      if((turnNum[maxCounter]) > max)
         max = (turnNum[maxCounter]);
  }
  turnNum[(childProc-1)] = 1 + max;
  printf("turnNum for process #%i = %i\n", childProc, turnNum[(childProc-1)]);
  choosing[(childProc-1)] = 0;
  for (j = 0; j < slave_max; j++)
  {
 while (choosing[j] == 1) {}
     while ((turnNum[j] != 0) && (turnNum[j] < turnNum[(childProc-1)])) {}
  }

  // critical section
  napTime = rand() % 3;
  sleep(napTime);
  sharedNum[0]++;
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &now);
  curTime = ((((long)now.tv_sec) * 1000000000) + (long)now.tv_nsec);
  // write message to log file here
     // for testing purposes:
     printf("File modified by process #%i (increment %i) at time %ld with sharedNum = %i\n", childProc, (i+1), curTime, sharedNum[0]);
  napTime = rand() % 3;
  sleep(napTime);

  // exit from critical section
  turnNum[(childProc-1)] = 0;
```

Comment: I the original algorithms, it doesn't matter if there is a race condition for `choosing` and `turnNum`; that is the idea of that algorithm. How do you get the idea, that this may be your problem?

Comment: @TonyTannous: Your hint is misleading. `fork()` creates a new process, not a new thread. Thus, it has its own address space, the memory is copied at the first write access, and you have two instances of the variable.

Comment: @Matthias: when testing, I had included a line to `printf` `turnNum[(childProc-1)]` and more often than not there would be duplicates per process. As in, multiple processes would print the same `turnNum` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered this a while ago, but forgot to provide the solution. It turns out that my implementation of the Bakery algorithm was fine. The real issue came from how I was initializing my shared memory segments in `slave.c`. By using different keys for each segment, I was able to run my `master` program with expected results.

updated "shared memory initialization" section of slave.c:

```
// shared memory initialization
shmkey = ftok("./master", 118371); // arbitrary key #1
shmid_sharedNum = shmget(shmkey, sizeof(sharedNum), 0600 | IPC_CREAT);
sharedNum = (int *)shmat(shmid_sharedNum, NULL, 0);
shmkey = ftok("./slave", 118372); // arbitrary key #2
shmid_choosing = shmget(shmkey, sizeof(choosing), 0600 | IPC_CREAT);
choosing = (int *)shmat(shmid_choosing, NULL, 0);
shmkey = ftok("./slave", 118373); // arbitrary key #3
shmid_turnNum = shmget(shmkey, sizeof(turnNum), 0600 | IPC_CREAT);
turnNum = (int *)shmat(shmid_turnNum, NULL, 0);
```